# Como hacer un foreach para recorrer una List<T>

Tags: c#, windows-forms, lista, opengl

He creado una lista de objetos de la siguiente manera (No sé si está bien):

```
   DatosPrimitivas primitiva = new DatosPrimitivas();
   internal List<object> VRectangulo = new List<object>();

   private void btnRectangulo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            figura = "cuadrado";
            //Cada vez que se presiona el boton se guardan los datos del rectangulo

            double.TryParse(txtAncho.Text, out primitiva.b);
            double.TryParse(txtAlto.Text, out primitiva.h);
            double.TryParse(txtAngulo.Text, out primitiva.theta);
            double.TryParse(txtDx.Text, out primitiva.dx);
            double.TryParse(txtDy.Text, out primitiva.dy);
            VRectangulo.Add(primitiva);

            glControl1.Refresh();
        }
```

La clase DatosPrimitivas que contiene las características que estoy intentando guardar:

```
    class DatosPrimitivas
    {
        internal double area;
        internal double b;
        internal double h;
        internal double cx;
        internal double cy;
        internal double dx;
        internal double dy;
        internal double theta;

    }
```

La intención es que cada vez que se pulse el botón y se ejecute su evento click se guarden los datos que el usuario ha introducido en una serie de textbox (son las caracteristicas (b,h,theta...) de una primitiva de OpenGL).
Una vez hecho esto querría recorrer la lista y poder obtener las características de las primitivas que se han tecleado para poder dibujarlas. 
**¿Alguna idea de como hacer esto ultimo?**

```
   internal void glControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {

^^Aqui tendría que estar el ciclo para poder dibujar las primitivas^^

}
```

Comment: de que tipo es primitiva? porque la lista no es de tipo primitiva en lugar de object? como estas declarando primitiva, porque parece que siempre guardas el mismo objeto.. cual es el problema que tuviste para recorrer la lista???

Comment: @gbianchi La primitiva es primitivetype.Quads y sí guardo todo el rato el mismo tipo, pero se supone que con diferentes caracteristicas... El problema es que no sé como se recorre la lista para volver a guardar las caracteristicas

Comment: por tu codigo, no parece que guardes diferentes valores.. siempre guardas el mismo objeto, al cual le estas cambiando valores... pero siempre es el mismo objeto, o sea que toda tu lista "apuntaria" a un solo objeto que tendra el ultimo valor ingresado. Respecto tu otra pregunta, no entiendo, un for no alcanza? o un while? o un foreach?

Comment: @Tormund Has probado con un simple **foreach** ?

Comment: @RafaelAcosta te importaría decir como sería?

Comment: @gbianchi pero al cambiar los valores no se formarían diferentes objetos? Esa era la intencion... Y respecto al bucle es que simplemente no se como plantearlo, es la primera vez que trabajo con una List

Comment: Una lista es como un array o cualquier otra estructura similar. No tiene complejidades.. miraste la documentacion de la misma? que tiene un monton de ejemplos de como recorrerla?? y aparte de eso, al cambiar los valores no cambia el objeto, si no que cambian sus valores ;)

Comment: @gbianchi Y como podría añadir  X objetos si cambio las propiedades X veces?

Comment: **primitiva.a** que es? un objeto y la propiedad **a**? . Existe la Clase `Primitiva`?

Comment: @Tormund: Creo que ya lo pillé ;). Estás intentando guardar siempre el mismo Objeto, pero con distintas propiedades?. y si es así **por qué**?

Comment: @RafaelAcosta exacto! Resulta que quiero tener todas las propiedades que el usuario teclee y luego poder dibujar los objetos con las propiedades que el usuario ha tecleado

Comment: He editado la pregunta añadiendo mas información que puede resultar de ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En principio, debes crear **un nuevo objeto** del tipo `DatosPrimitivas` cada vez que hagas click en el botón, y definir la lista `VRectangulo` del tipo `DatosPrimitivas`(**`List<DatosPrimitivas>`**):

```
    internal List<DatosPrimitivas> VRectangulo = new List<DatosPrimitivas>();

    private void btnRectangulo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        figura = "cuadrado";
        //Cada vez que se presiona el boton se guardan los datos del rectangulo

        // CREAS EL NUEVO OBJETO primitiva 
        DatosPrimitivas primitiva = new DatosPrimitivas();

        double.TryParse(txtAncho.Text, out primitiva.b);
        double.TryParse(txtAlto.Text, out primitiva.h);
        double.TryParse(txtAngulo.Text, out primitiva.theta);
        double.TryParse(txtDx.Text, out primitiva.dx);
        double.TryParse(txtDy.Text, out primitiva.dy);

        // LO AÑADES A LA LISTA ...
        VRectangulo.Add(primitiva);

        glControl1.Refresh();
    }
```

Luego recorres la lista con un `foreach`:

```
   internal void glControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {

        foreach (DatosPrimitivas item in VRectangulo)
        {
            // Aquí recuperas los datos de cada item
            var area = item.area;
            var b = item.b;
            ...
            ...

        }
    }
```